# Are global variables required for some types of DOM manipulation with javascript?

Tags: dom

In the example code below, I want to know why the variable called **child** must be global ( no *var*) in order for the code to work. I also want to know if the code below is considered bad practice due to having a global variable and how a better practiced rendition of the code below might look. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>dom</title>

<div class="product">
<h2> Product Name </h2>
<img src="pic.jpg" />
<p> Description </p> </div>

<script>
var products = document.getElementsByClassName("product"), 

        child;   // how come var breaks the code ?

    for ( i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        child = products[i].firstChild;
        while (child.nodeType !== 1) {
            child = child.nextSibling;
        }
        console.log(child);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a `var`, as there is a comma before child. Hence adding `var` would give you

```
var product, var child
```

which is illegal.

`child` is not global, because the `var` in

```
var product, child
```

applies to the whole list of variables following `var`. (Well, `child` is global anyway since it is not nested in a `function`. But that does not have to do with `var` or not `var`.)

If you insist on having `var` twice, write

```
var product = ... ;
var child;
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. It's not my code. I'm reading it out of a book and was curious about this. I got confused by the syntax